# Template does not display image - django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

i read tutorial "Tango with django" and i am on path to show images on my website. 
In settings. py file i pasted this lines in this step:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And in my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <a href="/rango/about/">About</a><br />
            <img src="{% static "images/rango.jpg" %}"
                alt="Picture of Rango" />
    </body>
</html>
```

path to my images file:

> application\website\rango\static\images\rango.jpg

I have no idea what am i doing wrong, i tried few other solutions but it does not work too.

Comment: Please update the question with a three of files. mapping the manage.py in relation to the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything known as `STATIC_DIR` in Django anymore.
Why are you even defining it in the first place.

Just use `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]`

This should work for you provided your `static` folder is at the `Base` Directory level i.e., at the same level as that of `manage.py`

Answer (score 0):

Only the following should be added to `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If you need to have that image in a different directory add the full path to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [<full path>]
```

**Important!** From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs):

> Note that these paths should use Unix-style forward slashes, even on
>   Windows (e.g. "C:/Users/user/mysite/extra_static_content").

An example on how you should organize your project:

`manage.py`

- `<project-name>`
- - `settings.py`
- `<app_name>`
- - `static/`
- - - `<app_name>/`
- - - - `img/`
- - - - - `rango.jpg`

this way you call:

```
<img src="{% static "<app_name>/img/rango.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Rango">
```

> Try learning from the [official
>   tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/),
>   it is really good and will get you used to look for stuff in the docs.